# How to save single quote with different languages in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-insert

I am Inserting Malaysian/Korean/Japaneese language in sql server, i am able to save it successfully but my code broken if any word has a single quote (Apostrophe). I tried following way but unable to save it.

- I am using SQL Server 2014.
- My saving word (Address1) is: **早'上好**
- My saving word (Address2) is: **早上好'**

SQL Query is following

```
 "Insert into Employee (CountryCode, Address1, Address2)values('" + Program.CountryCode + "',N'" + Address1.Text + "',N'" + Address2.Text)
```

During debug my query become with data as below.

```
 Insert into Employee (CountryCode, Address1, Address2)values('JP',N'早'上好',N'早上好'')
```

Comment: Do not concatenate strings to create your SQL, this makes your code potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks! Use SQL parameters instead (which also allow you to insert quotes).

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: are you inserting Malaysian/Korean/Japaneese, not Chinese?

Comment: Hi Lei Yang,

I used this word randomly, although we are using chinese as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all thank you so much for all respected comments which leads me towards proper solution, i am writing how i solved.

```
string add1 = txtAdd1.Text;
string add2 = txtAdd2.Text;
if(!add1.Contains(";"))
{
    if(string.isNullOrEmpty(add1) && add1.Contains("'"))
    {
        add1 = add1.Replace("'", "''");
    }
}
if(!add2.Contains(";"))
{
    if(string.isNullOrEmpty(add2) && add2.Contains("'"))
    {
        add2 = add2.Replace("'", "''");
    }
}
```

and i passed add1 and add2 into query as below.

```
Insert into Employee (CountryCode, Address1, Address2)values('" + Program.CountryCode + "',N'" + add1 + "',N'" + add2)
```

Comment: Building your own query text as opposed to using parameters (as also mentioned in comments) to supply values, is *not* a "proper" solution. Read up on "sql injection".

Comment: Hi Hans,

Then how can i pass the value as parameters?

Comment: Hi Hans,

I got solution, I should check for semi colon as well so it will not become a new query during execution.

Comment: See the link in the comment by Daniel Shillcock

Comment: Did you try your solution with `'); delete from Employee --` in your `txtAdd2`?

Answer (score -1):

Replace single['] quote with 2 single quote['']. This will solves your problem and insert a single quote with the data but field should be **nvarchar** in place of **varchar**.

Data''s in place of Data''s

Comment: Dear Yash,

Field is already nvarchar, i am able to save any language without single quote. code is failing if i am putting single quote.

Comment: No, don't use your own escaping (which may fail for things you didn't think about yet). Use parameters to supply values, then you are much safer.